# Where is the security tab in VS2017 when creating websites?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2017

Should hopefully be quite an easy one!

I'm aware in the older versions there was a security tab which helps when using the createuserwizard.

How can I access it in VS2017?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity